# Warning parameter names [When I try to load my array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I'm getting this message when I try to load my array using pointers.
I don't know why this keep appearing since the last program had no problem

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define T 10

void FLoad(int *);

void main () {
   int a[T];

   void FLoad(a);
}

void FLoad(int *a) {
   int x;

   for (x = 0; x < T; x++)
      scanf("%d", a+x);
}
```

And here is a little program that works perfectly

```
#include <stdio.h>

void FImp(int *, int );

main () {
   int a[] = {-10,-5,3,4}, tam;

   tam = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
   FImp(a, tam);
}

void FImp(int *a, int t) {
   int x;

   for (x = 0; x < t; x++)
      printf("%d ",*(a + x));
   putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: `void FLoad(a);` <- this is NOT how you **call** a function. Compare for yourself with your second program ...

Comment: side note: neither `main()` nor `void main()` is a standard conforming signature for main. Use either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You forgot to mention important things. What **exactly** is "this message" and where does the compiler complain? This information helps finding your problem as we don't need to check the whole code for any possible problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrect syntax when calling your function

```
void main()
{
    int a[T];
    void FLoad(a);
}
```

should be

```
void main()
{
    int a[T];
    FLoad(a);
}
```

or even better

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[T];
    FLoad(a);
}
```

You don't specify the function return value when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

```
void FLoad(a);
```

This won't call the function. The compiler will consider this as a function declaration. So call the function without void it will work fine.